# How to check if an object in an array has an empty string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object

How to check if an object in an array has an empty string?

```
var arr = [
  {name: "Bob", middle_name: ""},
  {name: "John", middle_name: "Denver March"}
];
```

Can I use something like this:

```
if (arr[i].middle_name === "") {
  alert("true")
}
```

While also making sure that it doesn't say true if the object isn't empty?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Here's an example of that.

```js
var arr = [{
    name: "Bob",
    middle_name: ""
  },
  {
    name: "John",
    middle_name: "Denver March"
  },
  {
    name: "Bill",
    middle_name: "Storm"
  },
  {
    name: "Empty person",
    middle_name: ""
  }
];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i].middle_name === "") {
    alert(arr[i].name + " is empty");
  }
}
```

Comment: I have a larger array I'm trying it on. Can I say 
`if (arr[i].middle_name === "") {
  alert("empty");
}`

Comment: @vindicta yes, I edited my answer to work with a for loop. This way, no matter how big the array, it will work.

Comment: what about if I have HTML part where I have a value from an input-box which would make you able to search for middle_name and have it display every object of my array that has no middle_name? Does my question make sense? Like

`var midname = document.getElementById("findMidname").value;`
`var arr = [{name: "Bob", middle_name: ""}, {name: "John", middle_name: "Denver March"}];`
`for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {`
  `if (arr[i].middle_name.includes(midname) === "") {`
    `alert(arr[i].name + " is empty");`
 ` }`
`}`

Comment: @vindicta what does the input do? Are you are checking if the middle_name is empty or if the middle name contains something that is in the input?

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for this job:

> The some() method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.

```js
const check = xs => xs.some(({middle_name}) => middle_name === "");
  
console.log(check(arr));
//=> true

console.log(check(arr2));
//=> false
```

```html
<script>
var arr = [
  {name: "Bob", middle_name: ""},
  {name: "John", middle_name: "Denver March"}
];

var arr2 = [
  {name: "Bob", middle_name: "John Doe"},
  {name: "John", middle_name: "Denver March"}
];

</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not skilled enough to use that

Comment: @vindicta Is there anything specific that you'd like me to expand on?